# pod Install unable to a source with url : ‘github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git named ‘cocoapods’

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, git, cocoapods

Am trying to run Chat SDK, but after running pod it’s taking forever to pass “cloning spec repo” even though I don’t even know why it is trying to clone.
Am lost, I tried bunch of things but am stuck here. Anyone for help please ??

After a while it gives me unable to add a source with url ‘github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git’ named ’cocoapods’ And cloning into ‘cocoapods’ error RPC failed, fatal the remote end hung up unexpectedly, fatal early EDF and fatal

Comment: Is your machine behind a firewall?  Do you need to use some sort of proxy?

Comment: The firewall is off, am using vpn sometimes cuz am in China. But i turned it off too when trying

Comment: You are having some sort of network connection issue.  Can you clone other repos from Github?